# System.Xml.Linq, Portable Libraries and Silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library

I built a portable class library (profile47, which includes Silverlight 5) that references System.Xml.Linq. I can reference that portable library from my Silverlight 5 application, and I can reference the Silverlight version of System.Xml.Linq in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client. The problem is that that System.Xml.Linq dll has a different version number (5.0.5.0) than the one referenced by the portable library, and when I run the Silverlight app it throws an exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As there isn't an assembly redirect mechanism in app.config like in full .NET framework, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I Think You Should Remove Old Reference And Add New Reference For System.link Version=5.0.5.0

Comment: I can't reference the Silverlight 5.0.5.0 version on the portable library version, only the 4.0.0.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the System.Xml.Linq reference from your portable class library. The .Net Portable Subset is enough if you have .net framework 4.0.3 in your profile.

Comment: I can't remove the reference because I'm using xml.linq in the portable library

Comment: Yes you can remove it even if you use Xml.Linq. If you get compile errors it is because your profile does not allow it.

Comment: The profile allows it, but I do get compile time errors. I'm reusing the same portable library on Widows 8 and Windows Phone apps, only the reference from silverlight complaints about different versions of system.xml.linq assemblies

Comment: Could you remove the reference from to System.Xml.Linq from your PCL and tell me what compile errors you get?

Comment: I double checked, and the problem was that I was referencing another PCL that was also reference System.Xml.Linq, after I removed it from all of them, I no longer have compile time errors, and if I reference System.Xml.Linq in the Silverlight assembly only, it now works at runtime. Thanks